# C++ Why Does Accessing Elements in an Array Return a Pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

My comfort language is Java, but recently I decided to learn C++ syntax.

```
int ks(int Wt[], int Va[], int N, int totW){

if(N==0){
    return 0;
}

int V[N+1][totW+1];

for(int i = 0; i < N+1; i++){
    V[i][0] = 0; // fill first row with 0's
}
for(int i = 0; i < totW+1; i++){
    V[0][i] = 0; // fill first column with 0's
}

for(int i = 1; i < N+1; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < totW+1; j++){
        if(Wt[i] <= j) {
            V[i][j] = std::max(V[i-1][j], Va[i]+V[i-1, j- Wt[i]]);
        } else {
            V[i][j] = V[i-1][j];
        }
    }
}
return V[N][totW];
}
```

This is my implementation of 01 knapsack. However, I get an error in the line:

```
V[i][j] = std::max(V[i-1][j], Va[i]+V[i-1, j- Wt[i]]);
```

The error reads:

> no instance of overloaded function "std::max" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (int, int *)

My question is, why does `Va[i]` return a pointer whereas `V[i-1][j]` doesn't?

Comment: `V[i-1, j- Wt[i]]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You probably want `V[i-1][j - Wt[i]]` instead.

Comment: be warned that the differences between java and c++ are more fundamental than syntax. Actually syntax is the only thing where the two have some similarities, but you better forget everything you know and learn c++ from scratch

Comment: `int V[N+1][totW+1];` is non standard C++, use VLA extension.

Comment: Or use dynamic allocation and delete it at the end (although OP, coming from Java, should do so with caution).

Comment: *My question is, why does . . . .*  `int Va[i]` doesn't evaluate to a pointer. `Va` is an array parameter that decays to a pointer. If you add the index `[i]` to `Va`, the i-th element of that `int` array is selected. So `Va[i]` evaluates to an `int` not a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`V[i-1, j- Wt[i]]` is not how you access a two-dimensional array in C++. In fact, there is no such thing as a primitive two-dimensional array, only arrays of arrays (that's what `V` is). You always need to access them with several consecutive `[]`.

The `,` in that expression (and in other expressions where it does not mean something else) is the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) that evaluates and then discards its left operand. So what your code tries to do is:

1. Calculate `i-1`, then discard the result.
2. Calculate `j-Wt[i]` and then access `V[j-Wt[i]]`. That's not what you wanted.

Comment: Wow, I completely misread how C++ does arrays. Literally same as Java. How embarrassing!

Comment: @LittleDragon The fun part about C++ is that you can create data structures that overload e.g. `operator()` and provide this exact functionality, so you can get `matrix(row, column)` accessors. Sadly, `operator[]` may only ever take on argument.